# PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions fails first time, works the second time

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I'm calling the logInWithPermissions with the default permissions, without any PFUser in Data Browser and permissions removed directly from Facebook.

The code called on the login button action:

```
NSArray *permissionsArray = @[ @"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"];

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
    // show an alert in case of error
}];
```

The first try returns an error **"com.facebook.sdk" - code: 5** without asking for Facebook permissions.

The second try asks for the Facebook permissions and upon confirmation, the PFUser is created and visible in Data Browser.

Does anyone have the same problem?

---

I'm using cocoapods with Parse v1.6 and ParseFacebookUtils v1.6 and I've followed the https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers/iOS guide